# Why I can't rename the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
          TAN.SK    SHA.LO
A         0.05      0.01   
S         0.04      0.44
D         0.08     -0.18
```

I would like the new df to be like:

```
          TAN        SHA
A         0.05      0.01   
S         0.04      0.44
D         0.08     -0.18
```

Basically remove from the column names `.SK` and `.LO`

This is what I have tried:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[0])

df.columns=df.split('.')[0]
```

This second case works perfectly in case of `df.index`

Comment: Thank you Psidom, my fault writing it wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DataFrame.rename()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) does NOT change the DataFrame in place (per default), so you have to assign it back:

```
In [134]: df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[0])

In [135]: df
Out[135]:
    TAN   SHA
A  0.05  0.01
S  0.04  0.44
D  0.08 -0.18
```

or

```
In [139]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[0], inplace=True)

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
    TAN   SHA
A  0.05  0.01
S  0.04  0.44
D  0.08 -0.18
```

Comment: Thank you Max ! That was the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think faster, if many columns, is use vectorized solution with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then select first `lists` by `str[0]`:

```
print (df.columns.str.split('.'))
Index([['TAN', 'SK'], ['SHA', 'LO']], dtype='object')

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]
print (df)
    TAN   SHA
A  0.05  0.01
S  0.04  0.44
D  0.08 -0.18
```